# How to get jQuery's timeago plugin to work

Tags: jquery, timestamp, timeago, human-readable

I've been trying to make time stamps human readable on this project I am working on by using the timeago plugin for jquery.

Here is the html code I have;

```
<dd id="dateJoined">2016-08-04T22:30:59.920516Z</dd>
```

and the following is a snippet from the script I am trying to get to work;

```
$('dd').addClass('timeago');
$("dd.timeago").timeago();
```

There are no syntax errors but for some reason it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

you are using a wrong HTML element, the correct one should look like the following code. 
Note: you have to add **datetime** attribute, otherwise it won't work

```
<time  id="dateJoined" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">2008-07-17T09:24:17Z</time>
```

where is a code pen as an example http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/wWYdVL

if you checked the  example you'll find 3 dates

1. HTML element + datetime attribute --> works fine
2. HTML element Without datetime attribute --> Doesn't work
3. dd  HTML element --> Doesn't work

Comment: yes, you're correct I've updated the answer with an example. please check

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for the answer but do you have any idea how I can edit the time stamp in the datetime attribute by using jQuery or javascript ?